# Will submitting new version of existing android app/apk be affected by Android App Bundle requirement?

Tags: android

I have an existing android app on google play store and constantly update to new version. I know that google going to rollout Android App Bundle in the coming August.
Will this rollout of Android App Bundle affects the existing app which needs to constantly (at least once a week) update (upload new version to play store) ?

Answer (score 1):

> I know that google going to rollout Android App Bundle in the coming August

App Bundles have been around for a few years. What is happening in August is that Google is *requiring* App Bundles for *new* apps.

> Will this rollout of Android App Bundle affects the existing app which needs to constantly (at least once a week) update (upload new version to play store) ?

If the existing app is already being distributed on the Play Store, my understanding is that it is not affected by this new requirement.